# lower semi-continuous map to a probability measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, continuity, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and $R(p)$ an interval with the property that both $\inf(R(p)):=\underline{r}(p)$ and $\sup(R(p)):=\bar{r}(p)$ are continuous and bounded functions of $p\in [0,1]$, with $\underline{r}(p)<\bar{r}(p)$ for every $p\in (0,1)$. Consider the function $\alpha(p):=\mu(R(p))$ for $p\in (0,1)$.

**Question:** Can we say that $\alpha(p)$ is lower semi-continuous for every $p$ such that $\alpha(p)>0$?

**Some notes:** Consider any sequence $(p_n)_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to some $p$. Suppose $r\in R(p)$ (since $p\in (0,1)$ $R(p)$ is non-empty). Since the boundary points of $R(\cdot)$ are continuous at $p$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\ge N$, $r\in R(p_n)$. That implies $R(p)\subseteq \liminf R(p_n)$. From Fatou's lemma, $\alpha(p)\le\liminf \alpha(p_n)$. This proves that $\alpha(p)$ is lower semi-continuous at $p$.

Is this correct? The argument does not depend on $R(p)$ being open or closed, but I think I this must matter. Under what conditions can we say that $\alpha(p)$ is upper semi-continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is valid if $R(p)$ is open but not in general. For example the end points of $[0,1-\frac 1 n]$ converge to end points of $[0,1]$. The point $1$ belongs to $[0,1]$ but does not belong to any of the intervals $[0,1-\frac 1 n]$. When the intervals are open your argument is correct.

Comment: Thank you! One additional question. When the interval is closed, then I can say that $\alpha(p)$ is upper semicontinuous, right? But how can I argue that $\limsup R(p_n)\subseteq R(p)$?

Comment: Use the following simple fact: if $a_n \leq x \leq b_n$ for infinitely many values of $n$, $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$ then $a \leq x \leq b$.

Comment: Got it! thank you.